# changing the value in a column, when the document is changed

Tags: column, documentation

Hope some of you can help me.

At the moment i am documenting a SharePoint.

I have made a column with the documentation number from the dokumentation system.

But now I would like the value of the column to change if there is made a new version of the document in SharePoint.

Anybody got some tricks?

OK Guys, thanks for the help so far. The problem is that when i enable versioning, somebody has to approve the version, and here that wont make any sense. The number has been attached by editing the properties of the document.

Comment: Are you referring to a document library within SharePoint? If so, they have a field called 'Version' that you can add to your list view.

Comment: Can you use C# farm solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply done by using an [event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx). Then bind it to your document library. Thereafter you can update the field on ItemUpdating event.

eg:

```
properties["Count"]= int.Parse(properties["Count"])+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the document at all. All you need to do is enable versioning into your SharePoint. SharePoint supports versioning by itself. Follow instructions in this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-HA102772148.aspx) to enable versioning.

Comment: Thanks so far, but then the problem comes when the version has to be approved. We don't wnat somebody to approve it. I've added the documentationnumber in hte properties of the document

Comment: http://www.pointbeyond.com/2009/08/31/configuring-approval-in-sharepoint
this can help you to know how to set the approvals (or not to set them at all) Search for info in google in this topic. If you like my answer please mark it as an answer.

Comment: After a bit more research, it seems that the problem is that the documents havn't got this number in its metadata, and therefore SharePoint still shows the property even after a new version is uploaded.